# Understanding nodejs memory leak

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks

I am currently working with a nodejs project where one of the controller looks following

```
var express = require('express'),
    router = express.Router(),
    blah = require('blah'),
    Foo = require('../models/foo');


/* Get all foos */

router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    Foo
        .getAll()
        .then(function (foo) {

            return res.json({
                foo: blah(foo)
            });
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            //handle error;
        });
});

/*
 *  Some other functions
 *
 */
```

The required module blah and the model Foo are used inside router endpoint. According to this article http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-memleak/, I assumed it will not be collected by garbage collector because of it being referenced by a closure inside it and might create a memory leak.

In that case what is the right way of releasing the memory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modules are cached in node.js so they should not leak.  They will be loaded once and then any subsequent time they are requested the originally loaded module is returned.  So, `require()` should not be generating a leak.  The initial load will take some memory, but subsequent loads should not take more memory.  If you call a module constructor or some other module method that uses memory, then that method stands on its own.

In your specific code, the modules `blah` and `Foo` are not leaking and are not eligible for garbage collection because they are used in a route handler that is still active and could still be called.  They are loaded once and are then available for use by the route handlers if/when they are called.  This isn't a leak.  This is the desired behavior.

If this isn't exactly what you were asking, then please clarify what you think might be leaking in the above code.

Comment: I don't need to use the Model Foo = require('../models/foo'); after I have done operation with it. So shall I assign it to null after finish working with it?

Comment: @MuhammadRaihanMuhaimin - First of all, setting `Foo = null` won't save you any memory.  The module is already in the module cache so doing that won't free anything.  Second of all, how can you be "done" with `Foo`?  Your `router.get()` registers a route handler that can still get hit anytime in the future.